# "We are currently experiencing service disruptions and are unable to provide quota information at this time." IN OAuth consent screen

Tags: service, oauth, quota

I created a new account fro using the YouTube API, But in OAuth consent screen page I see "We are currently experiencing service disruptions and are unable to provide quota information at this time." message. This message is also shown in other Google account as well. What is the meaning of this message?

[image]

Comment: I got the same message on a gmail api

Comment: I got the same error on calendar API

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming related. This is the support site for the service and we can't provide an answer about temporary disruptions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about support for a 3rd-party product.

Comment: I'm voting this up because I got the same problem and it's important first step in developing a google application

Comment: I got same message and voting. It seems that if an project that uses Google APIs is not verified by Google (is a test project) then it has some calling quota for sensitive user data. I had to  create a new project, new credentials etc. for my hobby app to work again.